# Holiday Hats Time Again - Please confirm if you are happy with hats

Tags: discussion

Once again the overlords in the mother ship are giving us a contest to have fun during the holidays

> As another year draws to a close, we wanted to do something fun and
>   lighthearted with our communities, as a way of celebrating the many
>   amazing people who make the sites awesome. So, we’re announcing Winter
>   Bash 2014!
>
> Most of you probably remember previous years’ events, but I’ll recap
>   anyway, for the newbies among us. Winter Bash is an annual event that
>   can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users
>   earn “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (analogous
>   to badges). Certain actions trigger the user receiving a hat, which
>   their gravatar can “wear”. We track everyone’s progress earning hats
>   in a leaderboard that looks something like this:
>
> [image]
>
> **This year the event will run from December 15 to January 4.** Individual
>   users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or
>   are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available.
>   And just like last time, at the end of the event, all hats will go
>   back into storage.

Please feel free to add your own answers, but do take the time to vote up the YES or NO answers I gave.

Comment: By the way, the community (and all of StackExchange) will default to participating this year.  That is different from last year, so please do make a case if you are bothered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## YES

I don't mind if hats happen on the site this year, and I know I can turn them off if I don't want to participate.

Comment: We are going for the hats again this year.

Comment: Yay! Yay! Hats!

Answer (score 1):

## NO

I don't think hats on the site are appropriate.

Comment: I `LOVE` hats!!!